# What will happened if some process need to allocate more then 2 GB of memory ?

Tags: .net, windows, memory-management, internal

As far as i know - any process in windows gets 2 GB of virtual memory address space ( in some cases 3 GB ) for allocation uses.

1. In what cases the process will get 3 GB and not 2 GB ? 
   Is there some way for the application developer to 'ask' the OS to allocate more then 2/3 GB of virtual address space ?
2. What will happened if the process need more then 3/2 GB ? ( i guess that the system will thru some 'out of memory exception' - but is there some way to avoid this case ? )

for example - what happened if the process is 'Microsoft SQL Server' that need to allocate much more then 2/3 GB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 32 bit process has a 4 GB address space, where usually 1 GB is reserved for hardware, and 1 GB is reserved for Windows. Using a [switch in boot.ini](http://www.maxi-pedia.com/3GB+switch+Windows+boot.ini+3+GB) you can make Windows give the process 3 GB of the address space.

A 64 bit process has a 16 PB address space. I don't know how much of that is reserved, but the usable address space is considerably larger than 2 or 3 GB.

Comment: Suppose an imaginary case that the process need more them MAX( addredd_Space_That_Was_Allocated) =>> that will happened ? and how can we avoid the exception ? ( if its possible ? )

Comment: @Yanshof for that scenario, you're only really talking about x86, and the answer is: "you can't". The only thing you could try would be having another process somewhere and shuffling data between them, but: if the OS is *also* x86 it hasn't really got anywhere else **itself** to get extra address-space from.

Comment: @Yanshof: It's not possible to allocate more memory than the address space, there simply isn't any more addresses that the process can use to access the memory. You have to change the settings and restart the application if you want the 3 GB address space. If you allocate too much memory you will either get an exception, or the process is closed, depending on what kind of application it is. (A web application running in IIS is much more limited than a desktop application.)

Comment: Actually, on a 32-bit server version of Windows you *can* allocate more memory than the address space.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

> As far as i know - any process in windows gets 2 GB of virtual memory address space ( in some cases 3 GB ) for allocation uses.

No, on x64 the virtual memory space is much bigger, which is why tools like SQL Server usually work best on x64.

Note that in current .NET there are limits on **individual objects** (strings, arrays, etc) to 2GB, but that looks to be going away soon (allowing for massive objects). See [gcAllowVeryLargeObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Ok, So again ( just for my system understanding ) - what if the process need more virtual address space then the OS gave ?

Comment: I understood the commentary for [`gcAllowVeryLargeObjects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054(v=vs.110).aspx) to mean that it was only going to relax the size constraint on arrays - if that's what you were referring to?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever arrays implicitly means "lists" too, since lists are backed by arrays.

Comment: But you say "(strings, arrays, etc)", whereas that page says: "The maximum size for strings and other non-array objects is unchanged."

Comment: @Yanshof the OS doesn't need to allocate it all from physical memory; there is swap space too... but ultimately, either the OS will provide an allocation, or it won't. The key point: on x64 no 2GB/3GB limit per-process exists.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever the only interesting one there is strings.